# puppeteer howto get element tagName

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I would like to get an element's tagName. Should be `button` in following example.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function run () {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  const html = `
    <div>
    <button type="button">click me</button>
    <span>Some words.</span>
    </div>
  `
  await page.setContent(html)
  const elements = await page.$$('button')
  const tagName = await elements[0].$eval('*', node => node.tagName)
  console.log(tagName) // expect to be 'button'
  await browser.close()
}

run()
```

The error message said `Error: failed to find element matching selector "*"`

I can tell `elements` matched one element as `elements.length` is `1`

Where is wrong?

========== Edit ==========

Let's say I already had `elements` beforehand, how to get the `tagName` out of it.

Thanks!

Comment: The `.$eval('*',` tries to find a *child* of `elements[0]` which is a `button`, right? But `elements[0]` is that `<button>`, it doesn't have children.

Comment: Oh I see. But how to get the `tagName`? I tried `elements[0].tagName`, it's `undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `page.$eval` to select the button, and then get the `tagName` from the button:

```
const tagName = await page.$eval('button', button => button.tagName);
```

If you already have an `elementHandle` like `elements[0]`, you can get an attribute from that element by passing it through `page.evaluate`:

```
const tagName = await page.evaluate(
  element => element.tagName,
  elements[0]
);
```

Comment: Thanks! But don't know if it'll be a solution for me.  In my codes I used `const elements = await page.$x(\`//*[contains(text(), "${text}")]\`)` to find the nearest element whose `text()` match `text`.  Then I would like to get the `tagName` of the elements for logging purpose. So I already had this `elements` before hand.

Answer (score 3):

It appears your `elements` is an array of `ElementHandle`s.

In that case, there may be a slightly more straightforward syntax:

```
const tag_name = await (await elements[0].getProperty('tagName')).jsonValue()
```

This does not involve referring to the page object.

Thanks!